# How to delete characters from in bash script?

Tags: bash, postgresql, csv

I'd like to insert data from `CSV` files to `PostgreSQL tables`, using path.
The name of file is `filename.csv`; The name of the table is `filename`. 
How can I delete the other parts of path as well as the `.csv` extension?

I use the following code but it doesn't work:

```
for i in 'ls ~/catalog/subcatalog/*.csv' ; do
  FILE = 'sed 's%~/catalog/subcatalog/%%g' $i'
  PGPASSWORD=$2 psql -q -U $1 -d testing -c "copy 'sed 's%.csv%%g' $FILE from $i delimiter ',' CSV'";
done
```

Comment: I think using a proper scripting language would make this much easier than a bash script...

Comment: There's no need to call `ls`: `for i in ~/catalog/subcatalog/*.csv; do`

Answer (score 1):

[You shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) output. You can do this in any shell:

```
for path in ~/catalog/subcatalog/*.csv
do
```

[You can't put spaces around an equals sign for assignment](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#foo_.3D_bar):

```
file='sed 's%~/catalog/subcatalog/%%g' $path'
```

To assign a variable to the value of a command, use a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
file="$(sed 's%~/catalog/subcatalog/%%g' "$path")"
```

But there's a simpler way to get what is called the base name of the file (that is, everything except the leading directories):

```
file="$(basename "$path")"
```

You'll need to [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting) to avoid problems with "special" characters like space:

```
PGPASSWORD="$2" psql -q -U "$1" -d testing -c [...]
```

The PostgreSQL command I'm not sure about, but if you find that specific command is not working you might want to ask another question with only that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `sed` operates on files or streams, not on variables.  But you don't need `sed` for this:

```
FILE=${i%.csv}
FILE=${FILE##*/}
```

This should remove the `.csv` extension from `$i` and store the result in `$FILE`, then remove the directory part.  You can verify the results by trying the above in the terminal directly.

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, you should vote it up or "accept" it by using the arrows and checkmark on the left.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basename this way:

```
...
FILE=`basename $i .csv`
...
```